# How to Install GDAL Python Bindings Alongside osgeo4w for a separate Python version

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w

I am currently attempting to install the C[hristopher Gholke distrubution of GDAL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) (and associated bindings) on a work computer as a dependency for a package. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481138/importerror-python-gdal-osgeo4w-installation) question is related, but I need to run the version of the Python bindings because it is a Python 3 module, so running through the osgeo4w shell is not sufficient.

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise.

When trying to import any variation on:

```
import gdal #or
from osgeo import gdal # or
import osr # or
import ogr # or
#etc
```

It produced the error

```
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I successfully installed the Christopher Gholke distribution of GDAL on a separate machine with no errors. The machine that had a succesful install did not have osgeo4w installed, which leads me to believe it is the problem.

Is there any way to successfully import gdal from a Python 3.6 shell with osgeo4w without throwing the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this particular machine did not have a Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio installed. After installing the distribution (specifically Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015) everything worked flawlessly with no further modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import library explicitly using below code which will add a folder of libraries to your python code and then you can Import the needed module (GDAL):

```
import sys 
sys.path 
sys.path.append("C:/ms4w/python/gdal") #Add this folder to python environment path
import gdal
```